# Live USB ignored during startup

Tags: installation, live-usb

I created a live USB using pendrive, but when I start my computer it simply ignores the drive. It tells me "No bootable device" (This is normal, there is no OS on the computer), but even when the USB is plugged in. I've tried reinstalling on the drive (no luck), and it won't boot to the drive even when the USB is manually selected from the BIOS menu.

Strangely enough, on another computer if I open the flash drive on windows and open "wubi.exe", then select to restart the computer, it boots from the drive normally.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure your BIOS is set to boot from USB.

Answer (score 0):

On some computers you have to press a key or key combination on startup to boot from CD or USB. On my Dell I have to press F12 to get a boot menu

Comment: I have done this before, to no avail. Selecting the USB from the F12 menu still doesn't boot to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which method you used to create the bootable USB drive. I have a positive experience with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) in windows and with Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu.